# Ingresar varios datos a un array nuevo

Tags: php

Esto intentando meter en un array nuevo los registros, pero sin meter registros duplicados. Tengo un array con RFC duplicados y estoy descartando los que estén duplicados, para eso estoy utilizado la función in_array de PHP, ya descarto los RCF duplicados y los meto en el array $pruebita todos los RFC, pero sin duplicarlos solo que ahora necesito meter también su nombre_cuenta.

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Código

```
<?php
  $array_cuentas = array(
Array ( 
        "troncal" => "2875", 
        "RFC" => "CAR080630JF6",
        "nombre_cuenta" => "Chacon & Rodriguez Asociados",
        "DIDS" => Array ( 
            525512090447), 
        "id_cdr" => "2875" 
), 
Array ( 
        "troncal" => "2777", 
        "RFC" => "ADA000803GM5",
        "nombre_cuenta" => "Almacenaje y Distribucion Avior SA de CV",
        "DIDS" => Array ( 
            525546249183), 
        "id_cdr" => "2773" 
), 
Array ( 
        "troncal" => "2876", 
        "RFC" => "TLE011122SC2",
        "nombre_cuenta" => "Tralix Mexico S de RL de CV",
        "DIDS" => Array (
            525512090445, 
            525526230587, 
            525552024342, 
            525552024546), 
        "id_cdr" => "2893" 
),
Array ( 
        "troncal" => "2893", 
        "RFC" => "TLE011122SC2",
        "nombre_cuenta" => "Tralix Mexico S de RL de CV",
        "DIDS" => Array ( 
            524421611002, 
            525512090438, 
            525512090439, 
            525552024483), 
        "id_cdr" => "2893" 
));

unificarTroncales($array_cuentas);

function unificarTroncales($array_cuentas){
    $pruebita = array();

    foreach ($array_cuentas as $key => $value) {
        if(!in_array($value["RFC"], $pruebita)){
            //Si el RFC no existe en el array $pruebita lo meto en el array, pero neecsito tambien meter el nombre_cuenta
          $pruebita[] = $value['RFC'];
        }
    }

    //Imprimo para comprovar que no se dupliquen
    print_r($pruebita);
    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para facilitar las cosas y evitar ciclos dentro de ciclos, simplemente crea dos variables: Una para almacenar solo los RFC y hacer la validación y otra para almacenar todos los datos que necesites:

```
<?php
$array_cuentas = array(
Array ( 
        "troncal" => "2875", 
        "RFC" => "CAR080630JF6",
        "nombre_cuenta" => "Chacon & Rodriguez Asociados",
        "DIDS" => Array ( 
            525512090447), 
        "id_cdr" => "2875" 
), 
Array ( 
        "troncal" => "2777", 
        "RFC" => "ADA000803GM5",
        "nombre_cuenta" => "Almacenaje y Distribucion Avior SA de CV",
        "DIDS" => Array ( 
            525546249183), 
        "id_cdr" => "2773" 
), 
Array ( 
        "troncal" => "2876", 
        "RFC" => "TLE011122SC2",
        "nombre_cuenta" => "Tralix Mexico S de RL de CV",
        "DIDS" => Array (
            525512090445, 
            525526230587, 
            525552024342, 
            525552024546), 
        "id_cdr" => "2893" 
),
Array ( 
        "troncal" => "2893", 
        "RFC" => "TLE011122SC2",
        "nombre_cuenta" => "Tralix Mexico S de RL de CV",
        "DIDS" => Array ( 
            524421611002, 
            525512090438, 
            525512090439, 
            525552024483), 
        "id_cdr" => "2893" 
));

unificarTroncales($array_cuentas);

function unificarTroncales($array_cuentas){
    // Solo RFC para evitar duplicados
    $rfcs = array();
    // Datos completos, sin duplicados
    $no_dups = array();

    foreach ($array_cuentas as $key => $value) {
        if(!in_array($value["RFC"], $rfcs)){
            // El RFC no existe en el arreglo $rfcs, insertar
            $rfcs[] = $value['RFC'];
            // También insertar en arreglo con datos completos
            $no_dups[] = array('RFC' => $value['RFC'], 'nombre_cuenta' => $value['nombre_cuenta']);
        }
    }

    //Imprimo para comprobar que no se dupliquen
    print_r($no_dups);
    // Devuelves por si necesitas el arreglo para algo más
    return $no_dups;
}
```

Comment: Ya lo termine haciendo un ciclo dentro de otro ciclo haaaaa, pero @Triby ya sabes que siempre aprecio tu ayuda y que te amo :3 <3

Comment: Ja, ja, ja, ja. Me alegra que hayas podido resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

Probaste a usar el array_push()

```
array_push($pruebita, $value['RFC'], $value['nombre_cuenta']);
```

o si lo quieres asi

```
array_push($pruebita, array("RFC"=>$value['RFC'], "nombre_cuenta"=>$value['nombre_cuenta']))
```

tambien con todos lo datos

```
array_push($pruebita, $value)
```

Comment: `array_push($arreglo, $nuevo_valor);` es exactamente lo mismo que `$arreglo[] = $nuevo_valor;`, la diferencia es que el primero genera una sobrecarga al llamar una función. Referencia: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php Además, no proporciona una solución al problema.